# To remove the deprecation in ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I'm using Android Studio and facing a problem. I need to remove the deprecation on the ActionBarActivity. The things I did to remove the deprecation are:

```
import the android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
```

but the result is still same. I need to make an app with actionbar so i need that.

[image: Code snippet]

Comment: Use `AppCompatActivity` from support library.

Comment: Too old question .Use `AppCompatActivity`